# Long request uri is getting truncated on calling redirect() function of a response object

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

In a particular Node.js code implementing custom authentication strategy for Passport.js (which employs Express 4.6.13), at some point next line is executed:

`return res.redirect(global.config.applicationEndpoint + '?user=' + queryUserString);`

It works fine until url passed to `res.redirect()` is short enough. If especially long `queryUserString` is passed (~8000 characters, or more), it still produces a redirect response with long and simingly-valid request uri in it, yet that uri is clearly truncated (ends preemptively) closer to its end. A couple of things to note:

1. A logging instruction placed right before that very line allows to conclude that right before `queryUserString` is passed to `res.redirect()` it's not yet truncated.
2. In redirect response this action produces in case of long `queryUserString`, though **request uri** IS truncated, uris passed in body of the response are NOT (they are the same uris). Yet, it still prevents my app from working properly (I need this long uri passed in request's header)

It's clear that some kind of limit is enforced here. But I can't find anything I could tweak to allow longer uris in requests.

Any help is appreciated, I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Which client are you using to check if your redirect works?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this will help, but I did some investigation into this.

Internally `res.redirect` calls `res.location`:

- Source: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L922
- Docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.location

Which we can then see that `res.location` just calls `res.set`:

- Source: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L884
- Docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set

But you can see there that there is a call to `encodeUrl` which an external dependency

- `encodeUrl` import: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L18
- `encodeUrl` source: https://github.com/pillarjs/encodeurl

Inspecting the source [here](https://github.com/pillarjs/encodeurl/blob/master/index.js#L58) reveals that there is some regex replacement going on:

```
function encodeUrl (url) {
  return String(url)
    .replace(UNMATCHED_SURROGATE_PAIR_REGEXP, UNMATCHED_SURROGATE_PAIR_REPLACE)
    .replace(ENCODE_CHARS_REGEXP, encodeURI)
}
```

My hunch is that your characters in your URI are being replaced which leads you to believe that it's being truncated.

I would check your URI against the regex patterns that the module uses:

- https://github.com/pillarjs/encodeurl/blob/master/index.js#L22
- https://github.com/pillarjs/encodeurl/blob/master/index.js#L29

Comment: "My hunch is that your characters in your URI are being replaced which leads you to believe that it's being truncated" - That's unlikely, I think. As I said, the same query string (same data passed in it, formatted in the same way(JSON object)), just not that long, works perfectly fine. Issue only happens when it exceeds some length threshold.

Comment: As I said, it is either the regex _or_ it's possible the call to `String()` is truncating it as well. It's strange though as my quick testing here says that `String()` can more than handle 8000+ characters.